# Building an aspx form to submit data to SharePoint web service to get data into list

Tags: form, web-services

Can someone point me at a good step by step tutorial that will show us how to build an aspx webform that will submit data to the sharepoint webservice to get data into a sharepoint list?

We want this, because we want to put forms on a separate site collection that anonymous users can submit data to a list, and not user Infopath.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the UpdateListItems method. My SPServices jQuery library can make this easier for you: http://spservices.codeplex.com. Oh, and it's free.